# GridLayoutの子Viewが画面からはみ出す

Tags: android

GridLayoutを使用して横2,縦4マスの表を作っています。「住所」と書かれたTextViewの右に住所を入れるTextViewが来るのですが、このTextViewが画面より右側にはみ出てしまいます。これを上手くGridLayoutの表示領域に合わせることはできるのでしょうか？

[image: GridLayoutスクリーンショット]

レイアウトXMLはこんな感じにしています。

```
 <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="電話番号"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tel" />

    <TextView
        android:text="住所"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:text="東京都港区六本木XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-123 456 789 000 123 456 789" />

    <!-- 以下略 -->
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```xml
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true">

  <TextView
      android:text="電話番号"
      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tel"
      tools:text="0123456"/>

  <TextView
      android:text="住所"
      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/address"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
      tools:text="東京都港区六本木XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-123 456 789 000 123 456 789"/>

  <!-- 以下略 -->
</GridLayout>
```